# How to add entry to MS SQL table?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a task that must keep data in MS SQL server. That is like simple registration form. I have to enter name, last name, address, and birthday and press submit button. After that the inputting data should be save in database. I don't know how to make it. Here is my code:

JSP PAGE:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Welcome to Test Project</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <a href="customerList.htm">Customer List</a>
            <h:form>
                <h1>Add person</h1>
                <p>Please fill in all fields and click Submit</p>

                <label id="firstNameLabel">First name</label>
                <input id="inputFirstName" value="${customerBean.firstName}"/>
                <label id="lastNameLabel">Last name</label>
                <input id="inputLastName" value="${customerBean.lastName}"/>
                <label id="nirthdayLabel">Birthday name</label>
                <input id="inputBirthday" value="${customerBean.birthday}"/>
                <label id="addressLabel">Address name</label>
                <input id="inputAddress" value="${customerBean.address}"/>
                <button id="addAddPerson" value="#{customerBean., hsr1)">Add new person</button>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Another JSP page:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Customer List</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Customer List</h1>
            <table border="1">
                <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Birthday</th><th>Address</th>
                <c:forEach items="${customerList}" var="customer">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${customer.firstName}</td><td>${customer.lastName}</td>
                        <td>${customer.birthday}</td><td>${customer.address}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
            <a href="addPerson.htm">Add new person</a>
            <a href="index.htm">Home</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Spring bean xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

        <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
              class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
              p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

        <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

    </beans>
```

More XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

        <!--
        Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
        for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
        define an explicit mapping for it.
        -->
        <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
              p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
              p:suffix=".jsp" />

        <!--
        The index controller.
        -->
        <bean name="indexController"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
              p:viewName="index" />

        <bean name="customerController"
              class="Controller.CustomerController"/>

    </beans>
```

web.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Hibernate configuration:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\TARAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
        <!--Add by myself-->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
        <mapping resource="Model/Customer.hbm.xml"/>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Java controller:

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Controller;

import Model.Customer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

/**
 *
 * @author Taras
 */
public class CustomerController implements Controller{

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("customerList");
        List<Customer> customerList;

        try{
                              //import from package Util
            Session session = Util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            customerList = session.createQuery("from Customer").list();
//            customerList.add(new Customer(new Customer().getFirstName(), new Customer().getLastName(),
//                    new Customer().getAddress(), new Customer().getBirthday()));
            mv.addObject("customerList", customerList);


             session.getTransaction().commit();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //customerList.add(new Customer("ds", "sf", "sfs", "sf"));



            return mv;
        }

        }
```

Generated java class:

```
        package Model;
         // Generated Mar 4, 2014 11:21:14 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA


        import java.io.Serializable;
        import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
        import javax.persistence.Column;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.Table;

       /**
        * Test generated by hbm2java
        */
        @Entity
        @ManagedBean (name = "customerBean")
        @Table(name="Test"
        ,schema="dbo"
        ,catalog="Test"
        )
        public class Customer  implements java.io.Serializable {


         private int id;
         private String firstName;
         private String lastName;
         private String address;
         private String birthday;

        public Customer() {
        }


        public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String birthday) {
           this.firstName = firstName;
           this.lastName = lastName;
           this.address = address;
           this.birthday = birthday;
        }

         @Id 

        @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(name="FirstName")
        public String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        @Column(name="LastName")
        public String getLastName() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @Column(name="Address")
        public String getAddress() {
            return this.address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Column(name="Birthday")
        public String getBirthday() {
            return this.birthday;
        }

        public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
            this.birthday = birthday;
        }


            //    public String addEntry(){
             // if (firstName != null && lastName != null && birthday != null && address       != null)
           //            return "";
             //        else
             //            return "";
             //    }

          }
```

Comment: Have you asked the google search engine?  There are probably about as many tutorials on how to do this as there are grains of sand on the average beach.

Comment: Wow that whole lot of irrelevant code... try jsp http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm